# dirichlet and gcds

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let (a,b)=1 and c>0. Prove that there is an integer x such that (ax+b, c)=1.

Right now, I have the following approach: 
Let's assume that for every x, (ax+b,c)$\neq$ 1. Then $\exists$ d, where d/c that also d/ax+b=> ax$\equiv$-b (mod d). I'm not sure how to continue from here on.

Comment: Divides is usually represented with the vertical bar $|$  For help on writing $\LaTeX$, you could see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course we should not use the fact that  there are infinitely many primes of the form $ax+b$ (Dirichlet's Theorem).

Let $P$ be the product of the primes that divide $c$ but do not divide $a$.

Since $\gcd(a,P)=1$, the congruence $ax+b\equiv 1\pmod{P}$ has a solution. Let $s$ be such a solution. We show that $as+b$ is relatively prime to $c$.

For suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(as+b,c)\gt 1$. Then there is a prime $p$ that divides both $as+b$ and $c$.

If $p$ divides $a$, then $p$ cannot divide $as+b$, since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

If $p$ does not divide $a$, then $p$ divides $P$ and hence $as+b\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. So again $p$ does not divide $as+b$.

**Remark:** We can replace $s$ by $s+tP$, for any integer $t$.

Answer (score 1):

The critical thing is that $d|ax+b$ for all $x$.  So take two different $x$'s and get $d|a$, then $d|b$ and you are done.